# Unable to plot a simple ellipse with units

Tags: plotting

I am pretty new to Mathematica. I would like to plot an ellipse:

```
Fell[x_, y_] := (x + c)^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = R^2
```

where $R$, $a$, $b$ and $c$ have units $m$ and are of the order of $10^6 m$.

However, I couldn't find a command that works. I tried Plot, Solve, Graphics, etc. but got a variety of errors or wrong plot where the frame is shown but not the function.

Can someone tell me, please, how to do that? I am sure it is pretty simple but couldn't find a solution around for two-branches functions with units.

Thx!

p.s. I add a result for the command

```
ContourPlot[
(Quantity[10^6*x, "Meters"] + c)^2/a^2 +
    Quantity[10^6*y, "Meters"]^2/b^2 ==
R^2/Quantity["Meters"^2],
{x, -10, 10},
{y, -10, 10},
FrameLabel ->
    Normal@QuantityArray[
            ConstantArray[ScientificForm@10^6, 2], "Meters"]
]
```

(see suggestion below:

[image: results of the above command]

Comment: ContourPlot but the best  be parametric equation and ParametricPlot.

Comment: can you please write a working example for this? I tried also ControuPlot but doesn't work 

    "ContourPlot[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 == R^2, {x, -R, R}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]"

gives:

    "ContourPlot::plln: Limiting value -6.3710088*10^6m in {x,-R,R} is not a machine-sized real number."

Answer (score 2):

As Kuba mentioned in the comments you need [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). Also note that you need `==` instead of `=`. The first is a test, the second is an assignment.

```
R = 1; a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
ContourPlot[(x + c)^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == R^2,
    {x, -10, 10},
    {y, -10, 10}
    ]
```

[image]

And just say all of the constants are in `10^6 m`

user1640950 was interested in seeing how this would work with units, which is done via the [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) interface. Note that if we had different units we'd have to use [`UnitConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html) to get them to align.

```
{a, b, c} = QuantityArray[{3.2, 2.6, 3}*10^6, "Meters"] ;
R = Quantity[6371, "Kilometers"];

square = 10^8;
ContourPlot[
 (Quantity[x*10^6, "Meters"] + c)^2/a^2 + 
   Quantity[y*10^6, "Meters"]^2/b^2 == 
  R^2/Quantity["Meters"^2], {x, -square, square}, {y, -square, 
  square}, FrameLabel -> 
  Normal@QuantityArray[ConstantArray[ScientificForm@10^6, 2], 
    "Meters"]]
```

[image]

Comment: so, there is no way to plot a function with unit in Mathematica? This sounds strange to me...

Comment: Like a `Quantity`?

Comment: maybe because I used for many years MathCAD, but there you can specify units very easily as soon as you define a physical quantity. This give you automated control on dimensional errors. I understand that this is not obvious in Mathematica.

Please note I am a newbie on Mathematica. So, I am still pretty confused about it.

Comment: Right. You handle units via the `Quantity` interface. I'll post an example of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help, but it doesn't work when I parse it.

The frame appears, but it's empty. I do not know how to post a screenshot of the result. However, the frame is there as expected, R, a, b and c have the expected values and units.

Comment: What are the expected values and units?

Comment: approximately a = 3.2 e6 m, b= 2.6 e5 m, c=3.3 e6 m, R = 6371 km. I added the plot directly in my questions for you to check. Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: So that was just a factor of the window not being large enough. I'll replace my other example with this so you can see it.

Comment: Thanks! thanks!! thanks!!! Now it works - kudos to MB1965 for the support! Now trying to understand the details...

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the `Circle` command. `Circle` can also plot ellipses.

```
r=1;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
Graphics[Circle[{-c,0},{a r,b r}],Axes->True,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r=5;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
Graphics[Circle[{-c,0},{a r,b r}],Axes->True,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]